# Why the letters do not come to the email?ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to configure native mailer on rails, and when I try to send a letter from localserver to the gmail mailbox, it does not work.

```
[18] pry(main)> user = User.last
  User Load (3.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<User:0x00000007a25150
 id: 1,
 email: "test@gmail.com",
 encrypted_password: "$2a$10$C2bkQfHAh4P6czCwuZdnn.bsnSM.tp8Rm7pHHn0S1MzAJ4ch.Jkea",
 reset_password_token: nil,
 reset_password_sent_at: nil,
 remember_created_at: nil,
 sign_in_count: 1,
 current_sign_in_at: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 13:52:09 UTC +00:00,
 last_sign_in_at: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 13:52:09 UTC +00:00,
 current_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255>,
 last_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255>,
 created_at: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 13:52:09 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 13:52:09 UTC +00:00>
[19] pry(main)> UserMailer.invite_email(user)

UserMailer#invite_email: processed outbound mail in 153.3ms
=> #<ActionMailer::MessageDelivery:0x3d72244>
```

`invite_email` method

```
  def invite_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
```

and development config

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 587,
      authentication: 'plain',
      user_name: 'email@gmail.com',
      password: 'pass'
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `deliver_now` or `deliver_later` (Or prior to rails 4.2, `deliver`)  on the return value to actually send an email:

```
UserMailer.invite_email(user).deliver_now
```